# How to show progressdialog in video view in android

Tags: android

In my activity I have a webview and a video. Both are loading from webservice. First I have to show the progress dialog for the activity after the webview has loaded. I have to show the progress dialog for the video view upto video is started.

Comment: You can check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802645/in-android-how-to-get-the-progress-time-of-the-video-played-under-videoview)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Showing progress Bar in Video view:
To display progress dialog while video is streaming you need to create class which extends aysnctask example test class. In that test class it is having three default methods like onPreExecuate(),donInBackground() & onPostExecuate().

In onPreExecuate() you need to set visibility of progress bar as visible & 
In onPostExecuate() just make it invisible to that you are able to see the progress bar while video is streaming.

This is what I used to display progress bar in video view.